# Refresh token validation fails with Codeception test

Tags: php, curl, codeception, oauth-2.0

I have a phpleague/oauth2 server implementation, which is working fine, ie generating access/refresh tokens, validating etc.

I have a following problem. When I refresh the token with grant_type=refresh_token with console curl, I successfully get the new access_token, but when doing this with a test:

```
$I->sendPOST('access_token', [
    'grant_type' => 'password',
    'client_id' => '111',
    'client_secret' => '222',
    'username' => 'exampleuser',
    'password' => 'examplepass',
]);

$I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
$I->seeResponseContainsJson(['token_type' => 'Bearer']);

// I receive a proper string, checked that out
$token = $I->grabDataFromResponseByJsonPath('$.refresh_token')[0];

$I->sendPOST('access_token', [
    'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
    'client_id' => 1,
    'client_secret' => 'pass2',
    'refresh_token' => $token 
]);

$I->seeResponseCodeIs(200); // Here I receive 403
...
```

I repeat, doing this manually in terminal works fine. 
After debugging it myself I found out that refresh token validation fails
at oauth2-server/src/Grant/RefreshTokenGrant.php at:

```
$refreshToken = $this->decrypt($encryptedRefreshToken);
```

But still I can't understand why it works manually. I did urlencode/urldecode and tons of var dumps, but still can't get the solution.